# "View Online" email appears blank

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

This is now happening for two clients of mine... the email is deployed and when we click "View Online" (using `%%view_email_url%%`) all of the personalization in the email is blank.

We are using AMPscript to personalize the email.

For one client, the DE is getting overwritten after deployment so I thought this might be the issue; however, it is happening for another client where we do not touch the email.

Perhaps something has changed?

For reference, this Q&A didn't help:  [view email / online version update when using ampscript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212540/view-email-online-version-update-when-using-ampscript)

Comment: So for the 2nd one the audience DE is not getting overwritten or cleared?

Comment: Correct.  The personalization is done via AMPscript and the DE is not overwritten.

Comment: I noticed you are using the wrong personalization string `%%view_email_online%%` should instead be `%%view_email_url%%`. Not sure if this was just a typo or not, but wanted to point it out.

Comment: Can you post some samples of the code being used and a screen shot of the output for us to reference?

Comment: I can't paste too much code, but it's straightforward enough I think:

`%%[IF EMPTY(@firstname) OR @firstname == "NA" THEN]%% %%[ELSE]%%
                                            <span style="font-family:'Avenir', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:18px; color:#000000; font-weight:300;">%%=ProperCase(@firstname)=%%</span><br/>
                                            %%[ENDIF]%%`

Is it possible the reason is that there is no primary key and my email address appears twice?  If so, what's the work-around?

Comment: BUMPing this up.. still have problems and the data extension used to deploy the emails is NOT being overwritten but the "view online" version of the email is blank where all of the personalization should be.  Help!